# Split a Dataframe per time interval

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
timestamp,name,age
2020-03-01 00:00:01,nick
2020-03-01 00:00:01,john
2020-03-01 00:00:02,nick
2020-03-01 00:00:02,john
2020-03-01 00:00:04,peter
2020-03-01 00:00:05,john
2020-03-01 00:00:10,nick
2020-03-01 00:00:12,john
2020-03-01 00:00:54,hank
2020-03-01 00:01:03,peter
```

I am trying to split this dataframe into many dataframes based on a time interval (for example 1 minute) and append the results into a dictionary.

I am trying:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/antonis/repos/newtest.csv')
minutesplit = {n: g.reset_index()
             for n, g in df.set_index('timestamp').groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='1Min'))}
```

but an error occurs like:

> KeyError: 'The grouper name timestamp is not found'

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are u grouping on? where's ur key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert column `timestamp` to datetimes by parameter `parse_dates`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/antonis/repos/newtest.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
```

And then convert to index by `set_index` with convert index to column by `reset_index` is not necessary, [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) is use parameter `key` for looking for column `timestamp`:

Here are keys in dictionary of DataFrames created by datetimes, so for seelcting is used `pd.Timestamp`:

```
minutesplit = {n: g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='1Min'))}

print (minutesplit[pd.Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:01')])
            timestamp   name  age
9 2020-03-01 00:01:03  peter  NaN
```

If keys convert to strings `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` is used `strftime`:

```
minutesplit = {n.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'): g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='1Min'))}

print (minutesplit['2020-03-01 00:01'])
            timestamp   name  age
9 2020-03-01 00:01:03  peter  NaN
```

If need list of `DataFrame`s:

```
minutesplit = [g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='1Min'))]

print (minutesplit[1])
            timestamp   name  age
9 2020-03-01 00:01:03  peter  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. Always you provide valuable answers. If I understand correctly, minutesplit is a dictionary which contains dictionaries?

Comment: @e7lT2P - it is dictionary of DataFrames.

Comment: So,  minutesplit[0] will give the first dataframe?

Comment: Can I ask something more? Is it possible to group every list with name?

Comment: @e7lT2P - Not understand, sorry. Can you explain more?

Comment: I wonder if I have many records in minutesplit[1], is it possible to group by name and produce something like [[peter], [[2020-03-01 00:01:03],[2020-03-01 00:01:05]]

Comment: @e7lT2P - Not so easy, maybe new question should  created.